# Smart pointer to container

Tags: c++11, stl, containers, smart-pointers

While sending stl container by reference it's not as safe as may be.
Does it make sense to wrap stl container by smart pointer to send as function argument?

```
template <typename T>
void f(const std::unique_ptr<T> up) {
  ...
}

std::unique_ptr<std::vector<char>> array;
f(std::move(array));
```

**UPD**: OK, let's narrow the question.
I'm making an instance of some class. I should construct it with a container:

```
class MyClass {
  public: 
    MyClass(const std::vector<int>& ar) : m_ar(ar) {};
  private:
    std::vector<int> m_ar;
};

std::vector<int> tmp_ar;
tmp_ar.push_back(0);
tmp_ar.push_back(1);
tmp_ar.push_back(2);
MyClass mc(tmp_ar);
```

I do not want to copy a container while sending it to the constructor, then I use reference to a local variable.
Something in this code makes me nervous.

Comment: why would sending by reference would not be safe? and sending by pointer would be?

Comment: I do not know, I'm still thinking ....

Comment: What made you to ask this question ?

Comment: @Drax It is quite important to know if it's sometimes necessary to allocate on heap a pointer to a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want to copy a container while sending it to the constructor, then I use reference to a local variable. Something in this code makes me nervous.

The code is correct as a *copy* of `tmp_ar` is being made by `m_ar(ar)`: *`mc` has no reference to the local variable `tmp_ar` so there is no lifetime dependency between `mc` and `tmp_ar`*. Problems can arise if an object stores a reference to another object and attempts to use that reference when the other object has been destructed (see [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), same applies to reference).

The `tmp_ar` could be [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)d instead to avoid the copy if `tmp_ar` is no longer required after it has been passed as constructor argument:

```
class MyClass {
  public: 
    MyClass(std::vector<int> ar) : m_ar(std::move(ar)) {};
  private:
    std::vector<int> m_ar;
};

std::vector<int> tmp_ar {0, 1, 2};
// Use 'tmp_ar' ...
MyClass mc(std::move(tmp_ar));
```